# Reloading the webpage will make the dropdownlist null

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load all the database agents into a dropdown list, and I want to insert the selected id into another table. Dropdown list function and insert functions are working, but after the page reload, the dropdown list return as null, and I am getting this error `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key AssignPerson` The code is mentioned below

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AssignPerson, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.users, "Select Assign Person", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult NewAccess()
        {
            List<Agent> countryList = _context.Agents.ToList();
            ViewBag.users = new SelectList(countryList, "AgentID", "AgentName");

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: on refresh your viewbag gets cleared and you arent reserving it.

Comment: Yes that is the problem I am facing @tstrand66